# flutter iOS has white screen

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I run my app on the simulator and keep getting a white screen. While the same works on an android simulator.

I'm not able to find a reason in the logs.

```
user:$ flutter run

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XR in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  

 ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                          16.6s
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        12.6s
Xcode build done.                                           39.8s
        path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
Failed to find assets path for "Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets"
Configuring the default Firebase app...
6.17.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000004] App with name __FIRAPP_DEFAULT does not exist.
        path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
[Crashlytics] Version 3.14.0 (144)
Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.
[Fabric] [Fabric +with] called multiple times. Only the first call is honored, please pass all kits you wish to initialize
[VERBOSE-2:engine.cc(127)] Engine run configuration was invalid.
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(437)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
        [C1.1 A86E5A82-4A2C-48C3-A211-EC9399A18596 192.168.2.103:61370<->216.58.207.67:443]
        Connected Path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0   
        Duration: 0.522s, DNS @0.006s took 0.060s, TCP @0.068s took 0.032s, TLS took 0.162s
        bytes in/out: 6279/1424, packets in/out: 10/9, rtt: 0.032s, retransmitted packets: 0, out-of-order packets: 0
6.17.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60202000 started 
6.17.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see xx://xx.xx/xx)
6.17.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031025] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
6.17.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled 
Syncing files to device iPhone XR...                                    
 9,472ms (!)
```

[image]

Comment: i had the same on android emu when not using `--enable-software-rendering` switch

Comment: Can you share your appDelegate.swift file and main dart file codes? (If possible, project itself)

Comment: thanks, --enable-software-rendering works.

Comment: good, i though it was valid for android only... ;-)

Answer (score 9):

as suggested by @pskink using --enable-software-rendering works.

flutter run --enable-software-rendering

Comment: it doesn`t work for me any solution for this?

Comment: did not work for me.

Answer (score 8):

1- rm -rf ios/Flutter/App.framework

2- Change the Runner target build settings Build Phases > Thin Binary script as follows:

```
/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" embed
/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" thin
```

Comment: Thanks... saved my lots of time.

Comment: Thanks a ton, man! This really worked and saved me lots of time and nerves

Comment: Thanks a million, man! Spent a day trying to fix this with no results until I found this.

Comment: Thanks man . saved my day . Can you please explain why this is happening ?

Comment: did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
Try to upgrade flutter to the latest.

```
flutter upgrade
```

then clean the project.

```
flutter clean
```

Try running again